# Select all Child Table ID for a Matching Parent of a Child

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have these tables below.. (I have omitted other unnecessary columns for readability)

Teams - TeamID, TeamName

TeamMembers - TeamMemberID, TeamID, MemberName

BoothVisitLog - BoothVisitLogID, BoothID, Visited By(MemberID)

For E.g. Say a TeamMember with ID 1 visits a BoothID 1. Now I want to find if any member of same team has visited the booth.

I have written the below query which is working fine. But I'm more inclined towards writing better optimized query instead of using Sub Query. Is there any way I can use join to achieve the same?

```
SELECT * FROM BoothVisitLog BVL INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TM.MemberID FROM TeamMembers TM 
    INNER JOIN Teams T ON TM.TeamID = T.TeamID 
    WHERE T.TeamID IN
    (
        SELECT TM.MemberID FROM TeamMembers TM 
        INNER JOIN Teams T ON TM.TeamID = T.TeamID 
        WHERE TM.MemberID = 1
    )
) TTM ON BVL.VisitedBy = TTM.MemberID AND BVL.BoothID = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As booth id is `1` , only thing that matters is the team of member id `1`

this will give the results you want

```
SELECT BL.* FROM BoothVisitLog BL
JOIN TeamMembers TM
ON  BL.BoothID =1
AND TM.MemberID = BL.VisitedBy
JOIN
( select TeamID from TeamMembers where MemberID =1) T
ON T.TeamID = TM.TeamID
```

In case you want to know the results for all booths that are visited by Member ID `1` that are also visible by the team members, you can get the result using `self join` on BoothVisitLog table.

```
 SELECT BL2.* FROM BoothVisitLog BL1
JOIN BoothVisitLog BL2
on BL1.BoothID = BL2.BoothID 
AND BL1.VisitedBy =1
JOIN TeamMembers TM
on TM.MemberID = BL2.VisitedBy
JOIN
( select TeamID 
  from TeamMembers where MemberID =1) T
ON T.TeamID = TM.TeamID
```